# UK passport photo not enclosed

Tags: visas, uk

Hopefully someone can answer me soon.

Today I went to VFS and submitted my documents. The VFS employee was nice enough, signed the checklist and reviewed my supporting documents. But I forgot to mention/ask about my pictures.

I know I also failed as I am supposed to just give it to them. It was an honest mistake. I did place them on top of my passport inside my folder. But unfortunately I have not been able to grab the pictures. She took my passport but she did not ask for my pictures after checking all of the documents.

Did anyone experience the same thing? Can I still send them? Will VFS help me as there is also an opportunity on their part. Or just wait for the visa refusal pack?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Omitting an essential part of the application like a photo will not lead to a refusal (a judgement that you aren't allowed to enter the UK, which will be permanently recorded).  The worst-case scenario is that your application will be rejected as invalid. You will have to submit it again, but this has no permanent consequences.  Your application fee will be refunded, as well.

However, it may be possible to send the photos separately and have them added to your application.  In at least some cases, you can send more documents later to support the application, but I don't know if this would be possible with the photos.  Also it may depend on the type of application.  I haven't been able to find clear guidance on this.

I suggest contacting VFS, as they may have a good idea of what is possible.  Also, given that it was their mistake, perhaps they will put some effort into helping you correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your response @dan111.. The visa I have applied is the standard visit visa. I've only just submitted it yesterday. I will contact VFS on Monday first thing in the morning.